# Unable to add row in middle of two rows using Index No

Tags: javascript, html

I have dynamically created a table now I want to add row in between already existed 2 rows I am trying below code but its not working

```
 var newRow = '<tr id="' + RowCountDoctorVisit + '">' +
                                '<td ><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="removeRowDoctor(' + RowCountDoctorVisit + ');"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>&nbsp;' +
                                   '<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="EditDoctorRow(' + RowCountDoctorVisit + ');"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>' +
                                '</td>' +
                                '<td class="column" data-label="DoctorName">' + DoctorName +
                               '</td><td style="display:none;" data-label="DoctorID">' + DoctorID +
                               '<td class="column" data-label="Visit Type">' + VisitType +
                               '</td><td style="display:none;" data-label="Visit Type ID">' + VisitTypeID +
                                '<td class="column" data-label="Room Group Name">' + RoomGroupName +
                               '</td><td style="display:none;" data-label="Room Group ID">' + RoomGroupID +
                               '</td><td class="column" data-label="Rate">' + Rate +
                               '</td><td class="column" data-label="Unit">' + Unit +
                               '</td><td class="column" data-label="Amount">' + Amount +
                               '</tr>'

document.getElementById("DoctorIndex").value contains index number
    $('table#DoctorVisit > tbody > tr:eq(' + document.getElementById("DoctorIndex").value + ')').after(newRow);
```

Comment: So what happens? Errors? What is `newRow`? Did you check `document.getElementById("DoctorIndex").value` value?

Comment: I have edited newRow =  the row i want to add with data
And `document.getElementById("DoctorIndex").value` contains Index no

Answer (score 0):

I tried something like this and it works but if i want to use newRow variable to add whole row

```
var tbl = document.getElementById("DoctorVisit");
            var indexno = document.getElementById("DoctorIndex").value;
            var row = tbl.insertRow(indexno);
            row.id = RowCountDoctorVisit;
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        cell1.className = 'column';
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        cell2.className = 'column';
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        cell3.className = 'dynamicallyHiddenRow';
        var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
        cell4.className = 'column';
        var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
        cell5.className = 'dynamicallyHiddenRow';
        var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
        cell6.className = 'column';
        var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
        cell7.className = 'dynamicallyHiddenRow';
        var cell8 = row.insertCell(7);
        cell8.className = 'column';
        var cell9 = row.insertCell(8);
        cell9.className = 'column';
        var cell10 = row.insertCell(9);
        cell10.className = 'column';
        cell1.innerHTML = '<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="removeRowDoctor(' + RowCountDoctorVisit + ');"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>&nbsp;<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="EditDoctorRow(' + RowCountDoctorVisit + ');"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>';
        cell2.innerHTML = DoctorName;
        cell3.innerHTML = DoctorID;
        cell4.innerHTML = VisitType;
        cell5.innerHTML = VisitTypeID;
        cell6.innerHTML = RoomGroupName;
        cell7.innerHTML = RoomGroupID;
        cell8.innerHTML = Rate;
        cell9.innerHTML = Unit;
        cell10.innerHTML = Amount;
```